# How to update a value in an array of structs in a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following schema:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
... SNIP ...
 |-- foo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
... SNIP ...
 |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value2: double (nullable = true)
```

In this case, I only have one row in the dataframe and in the `foo` array:

```
>>> df.count()
1
>>> df.select(explode('foo').alias("fooColumn")).count()
1
```

`value` is null:

```
>>> df.select(explode('foo').alias("fooColumn")).select('fooColumn.value','fooColumn.value2').show()
+-----+------+
|value|value2|
+-----+------+
| null|  null|
+-----+------+
```

I want to edit `value` and make a new dataframe.  I can explode `foo` and set `value`:

```
>>> fooUpdated = df.select(explode("foo").alias("fooColumn")).select("fooColumn.*").withColumn('value', lit(10)).select('value').show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   10|
+-----+
```

How do I collapse this dataframe to put `fooUpdated` back in as an array with a struct element or is there a way to do this without exploding `foo`?

In the end, I want to have the following:

```
>>> dfUpdated.select(explode('foo').alias("fooColumn")).select('fooColumn.value', 'fooColumn.value2').show()
+-----+------+
|value|value2|
+-----+------+
|   10|  null|
+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` function to update each struct in the `foo` array.

Here's an example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- foo: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- value2: long (nullable = true)

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "foo",
    F.expr("transform(foo, x -> struct(coalesce(x.value, 10) as value, x.value2 as value2))")
)
```

Now, you can show the value in `df1` to verify it was updated:

```
df1.select(F.expr("inline(foo)")).show()
#+-----+------+
#|value|value2|
#+-----+------+
#|   10|    30|
#+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this @blackbishop.  It is close to what I need, but it means that it loses all the other columns in foo.  I need to preserver those and just edit the value column.

Comment: @doc I updated my example to show how to preserve other fields of the struct

Comment: That's great @blackbishop.  My actual schema has about 20 columns under foo, so I had to write a big expression but it worked nicely. Thanks